# First Isabelle example

Tags: isabelle

Been trying to reproduce the short example in 3rd tutorial by Mohamed Abouelwafa on YouTube but can't get past the parsing error. Mohamed shows how to input the double right arrow as == but that doesn't seem to work on my Isabelle 2019, so I used Symbols/Arrow to get it. Other than that I can't think of anything, but still can't get this to work. Whatever I tried it doesn't parse. Help anyone? Thanks!

```
theory example
imports FOL
begin

lemma ex1: "⟦ A; B ⟧ ⟹  A ⋀ B" 
  apply (rule conjI)
  apply assumption
  apply assumption
  done

end
```

Answer (score 2):

When I copied your code into Isabelle, I found what appears to be a typo: "A ⋀ B" rather than "A ∧ B"

They look very similar on StackOverflow, but in Isabelle the former is much bigger and is not the correct symbol to use.

When I changed it to the latter symbol, ∧, the parsing error went away and the proof successfully completed.  If you start typing `\and` it will allow you to select the correct symbol from a drop-down menu.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, it does! The video didn't say which one to use, so I was confused and thought they were the same. Time to start using Isabelle for real. What is the best place to look for examples of proofs by induction, say 1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2 or similar? Thank you again!